# ifstream unable to read file

Tags: c++, fstream

I've been trying to make a console application in Visual Studio 2015 which will read a text file to a string and then output the string, but I'm having some problems.

The first thing I tried was following the cplusplus.com tutorial:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string line;
    ifstream myfile("test.txt");
    if (myfile.is_open())
    {
        while (getline(myfile, line))
        {
            cout << line << '\n';
        }
        myfile.close();
    }

    else cout << "Unable to open file";
    return 0;
}
```

The program didn't open the file.

Despite multiple internet searches and trying over 20 different methods, I still haven't been able to get my program to work. The best result I was able to achieve was a row of meaningless 0s.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: are you sure the file is in the right directory?

Comment: Where is the text file located?

Comment: You should run the program in a console.

Comment: _"The program didn't open the file."_ Your question title totally differs from your actual question title. For starters apply the full file path for opening, in a second step check if your program runs with the same working directory where that file resides.

Comment: Why not use cin and cout, and call your application piping the file to it that you want to interpret?

Comment: Are you running the program in a console, or from an IDE?

Comment: @tobi303 The text file is located in the same folder as the program, but I don't know if this is where I should put it.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg A console, I believe. Win32.

Comment: How exactly are you executing the program?

Comment: And the file `test.txt` is in the same directory as you are when you run your program?I mean, it doesn't have to be the same directory where the program is, just where you are. I.e. if you do `cd \foo\bar` then the file should be `\foo\bar\test.txt`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are doing wrong is not emitting a useful error message.  Rather than printing "Unable to open file", let the computer tell you why it couldn't open the file.  For example:

```
#include <iostream>                                                                                
#include <fstream>                                                                                 
#include <string>                                                                                  
                                                                                                   
using namespace std;                                                                               
                                                                                                   
int main(int argc, char **argv)                                                                   
{                                                                                                  
    int rv = 0; 
    string line;                                                                                   
    const char * path = argc > 1 ? argv[1] : "test.txt";                                           
    ifstream myfile(path);                                                                         
    if( myfile.is_open() ){                                                                        
        myfile.close();                                                                            
    } else {                                                                                       
        perror(path);
        rv = 1;                                                                              
    }                                                                                              
    return rv;                                                                                      
}
```